# What is the number of monotone Boolean functions of $n$ variables?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

I am looking at OEIS sequence A000372 titled: "Dedekind numbers or Dedekind's problem: number of monotone Boolean functions of $n$ variables, number of antichains of subsets of an $n$-set, ..."

I do not understand what is a monotone Boolean function of $n$ variables.  I understand the second description in the title, number of antichains of subsets of an $n$-set.  Can anyone give me a more clear definition of what is being counted in the first description of the title?  A small example (say for $n =3$) would probably help me the most).  Is there any "easy" bijection between the two descriptions?

Comment: I had a very similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762427/no-of-boolean-functions-of-n-variables-constructible-from-and-and-or-but-wit) about 1.5 years ago.  You might find my OP itself and the answers helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Boolean algebra we define $\,0<1.\,$ A Boolean function
is monotone iff $\,f(x)\,$ satisfies $\,f(x)\le f(y)\,$
 for every $\,x\le y\,$.
This is generalized to multiple variables by defining, e.g.,
$\,(x_1,y_1)\le(x_2,y_2)\,$ iff $\,x_1\le x_2\,$ and
$\,y_1\le y_2.\,$ Thus $\,f(x,y)\,$ is a monotone function
iff $\,f(x_1,y_1)\le f(x_2,y_2)\,$ for every
$\,(x_1,y_1)\le(x_2,y_2).\,$

The connection is that a Boolean vector
$\,X:=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)\,$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)
 of a subset $\,S\,$ of $\,\{1,2,\dots,n\}\,$
 where $\,k\in S\,$ iff $\,x_k=1.\,$